# Force redirection to HTTPS with query params by HAProxy

Tags: apache, https, apache2, haproxy, redirect

I am using HaProxy to load balance incoming requests and do sub-domain based redirection. Now I want to make all incoming request forcefully HTTPS, with query params.

For ex:-

http://foo.test.com/test_page?person_name="Bla"

Should get redirected to :-

https://foo.test.com/test_page?person_name="Bla"

I know I can do such kind of redirection using Apache:-

```
   RewriteEngine On
   # This will enable the Rewrite capabilities
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   # This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
   #RewriteRule ^/?(.*) HTTPS_REDIRECTION_LOGIC{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Or Can I do such redirection using apache listening on port 80, and make redirected HA-Proxy to listen re-directed request on prt 443, both running on same box? I tried this approach but whenever Apache starts it is binding with both port 80, and 443.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use haproxy version 1.5.x (as of June 2014, it has been announced as stable).
A simple code snippet in your haproxy.cfg should sort it out for you:

```js
frontend http-in
        bind *:80
        redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

frontend https-in
        bind *:443
        <other configuration>
```

cheers :)

Answer (score -1):

Put in your vhost:

```
UseCanonicalName on
UseCanonicalPhysicalPort On
```

And use the SERVER_PORT instead HTTPS
example:

```
RewriteEngine On
   # This will enable the Rewrite capabilities
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
   # This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
   #RewriteRule ^/?(.*) HTTPS_REDIRECTION_LOGIC{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

OR

you can use the domain to redirect

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$ [R=302,L]
```